# Why does a .cpp file get wrong extension when downloaded with data download anchor?

Tags: html, mime-types

I have the following HTML code:

```
<a href="data:text/x-c;charset=utf-8,struct%20example%20%7B%0A%09int%20number%20%3D%205%3B%0A%7D%3B"
   download="example.cpp" target="_blank">Download a struct stub</a>
```

but for some reason, clicking this anchor results downloading an `example.cp` file and not `example.cpp`. I think I've checked everything. For instance, for `.json` files it works correctly. Also `text/x-c` is the right `Content-Type` for `.cpp` files. I've also tried with `text/plain`, but it still kept getting changed to `.cp`. Why does this happen and is there a workaround to it? I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Seems to work for me - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMGR7IYZJ78G

Comment: I've just tested it on Safari and it works too. Perhaps it's a Chrome or Webkit issue then?

Comment: I've also just tried with different .cpp files, actually not only from data download anchors, but also from Dropbox, and every time .cpp extension gets changed to .cp.

Comment: Maybe something to do with this? https://fileinfo.com/extension/cp

Comment: It happened to me too. It is so stupid when os automatically change the user filename.

Comment: May be caused by [a security feature](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources) of the HTML Standard.  There's a workaround using Blob [on a similar issue reported in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182#c69).

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2022: I have the same issue when trying to download .cpp files using Google Chrome.

Switching to Safari and Firefox works for me.